# Java code for download file from company sharepoint server

Tags: java, file, sharepoint, download

I tried to download a file from company.sharepoint server but 
no success from java code.
I got 503 Service Unavailable.
I can access the file from browser with my account ( user/pass ).
I see https in browser.
This is strange!

Has the server a configuration problem ?

I tried with

```
credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, 
new NTCredentials(user, pwd, "", ""));
HttpHost target = new HttpHost("company.sharepoint.com", 80, "http");
or
HttpHost target = new HttpHost("company.sharepoint.com", 443, "https");
```

No success... I got 503 Service Unavailable.

I tried different codes 
and I noticed that there is a redirection from 
company.sharepoint.com server to login.microsoftonline.com/...

I tried with no success to use web services from share point and generate
code from wsdl

model 
wsimport -d e:\tmp6\ -p at.company.commons.io.sharepoint.copy 
-keep -extension -Xnocompile e:\tmp6\Copy.wsdl

Can you tell us an example how to download a file from share point ?

Please.
Thank you.